# Custom X86_64 calling convention to C function call

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, libffi

I've to do an interface (say, a wrapper) that allow a call from X86_64 assembly code using his calling convention to C function, with other calling convention. The best thing would be to be pretty "compiler independant" (juste modifying the wrapper), so i'm looking for something that puts registers/stack stuff on compiler back. I've already look here : [Custom calling convention for P/Invoke and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390798/custom-calling-convention-for-p-invoke-and-c) and it's come close from what i've to do. Currently, I'm using GCC, but hints from other compilers are welcome !

So, here is the thing, for a best view of the problem (the custom coding convention is strange ) :

```
pushq  %r11    # saves r11 for call
movq 64bits_address %r11 # move a 64 bits address that points on a data structure
callq *8(%r11) # calls an address in the data structure
popq %r11      # restores %r11 ; return value is in the structure
```

I need to be able to call a "special" (wrapper) C function ; here job will be to dispatch calls between other C functions. So this wrapper needs to find %r11, save all registers and prepare the stack for further call. Is there a proper way to do this in C (with some inline asm) ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Visual C++ has a `__declspec(naked)` modifier that prevents the compiler from generating prologue and epilogue.

Comment: __declspec(naked) is not supported when compiling for x64 targets (and inline assembly too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For documentation about calling conventions and how are the parameter passed to a function (in registers? which? what's on the stack etc) have a look at [Agner Fog's document](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).

Then, you can have a look at [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/)'s source code to see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks for answering ;
I didn't know libffi, i'm gonna check this, it's sound great.

Comment: If I were you, if possible, I would just rely on libffi. It's stable, maintained and handles many corner cases

Comment: OK, Agner Fog's document is very useful. But libffi does not save all registers, in particular YMM registers (not yet ?).
By the way, i should be able to do some stuff with that !
Thanks a lot.